# Problem in solving an equation with bessel functions

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

I'm trying to solve an equation of the following form but I can't find what I'm doing wrong.

I also tried `NSolve` instead of `Solve` but no results again.

```
L = 26;
h = 0.01;
\[Rho] = 0.1;
x[f_] = h Sqrt[f^2 - L^2*\[Pi]^2];
y[f_] = h Sqrt[Abs[L^2 *\[Pi]^2 - \[Rho]*f^2]];
NSolve[-1/x[\[Omega]]*BesselJ[1, x[\[Omega]]]/
    BesselJ[0, x[\[Omega]]] - 
   1/y[\[Omega]]*BesselK[1, y[\[Omega]]]/BesselK[0, y[\[Omega]]] == 
  0, \[Omega]]
```

Comment: Please, always post copyable code. Try `NSolve` and `FindRoot` for numerical solutions.

Comment: Multiplication is signified by either `*` or a space not `x`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I thought maybe the colors of characters would matter. I'll add code too.

Comment: @BobHanlon Tried it. Still no change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
L = 26;
h = 1/100;
ρ = 1/10;
x[f_] = h Sqrt[f^2 - L^2*π^2];
```

**EDIT:** Thanks to comment by [`Akku14`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/34287/akku14), changed definition of `y[f]` to make the use of `NSolve` more robust

```
(* y[f_]=h Sqrt[Abs[L^2*π^2-ρ*f^2]]; *)

y[f_] = h ((L^2*π^2 - ρ*f^2)^2)^(1/4);


expr[ω_] = -1/x[ω]*
    BesselJ[1, x[ω]]/BesselJ[0, x[ω]] - 
   1/y[ω]*BesselK[1, y[ω]]/BesselK[0, y[ω]];
```

Specify a range of interest

```
sol = NSolve[{expr[ω] == 0, -1000 < ω < 1000}, ω, Reals]

(* {{ω -> -894.145}, {ω -> -579.459}, {ω -> -255.326}, {ω -> 255.326}, 
    {ω -> 579.459}, {ω -> 894.145}} *)

Plot[expr[ω], {ω, -1000, 1000}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], 
   Point[{ω, expr[ω]} /. sol]}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** `expr` is an even function of `ω`

```
expr[-ω] == expr[ω] // ComplexExpand

(* True *)
```

Comment: Beaten just for seconds :))  (+1) ...

Comment: Works great. But when I set L=92 the output line is the same as the NSolve and no roots are displayed. But the plot has roots. Why?

Comment: Maybe your function is complex in some range. Try to find the roots of `Abs[expr[\[omega]_]]`

Comment: Use  `y[f_] = h Sqrt[Sqrt[(L^2*\[Pi]^2 - \[Rho]*f^2)^2]]; ` and it workes very well.  The `Abs `makes problems to `NSolve ` .

Comment: @Akku14 The thing to keep in mind is that there are powerful techniques for finding roots of analytic functions over bounded domain.  `Abs[z]` is not analytic.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `FindInstance` and bound the range for $\omega$.

Firstly, we can see that your function has many roots:

[image]

So within the range plotted:

```
N@FindInstance[Numerator@
 Together[-1/x[\[Omega]]*
    BesselJ[1, x[\[Omega]]]/BesselJ[0, x[\[Omega]]] - 
   1/y[\[Omega]]*
    BesselK[1, y[\[Omega]]]/BesselK[0, y[\[Omega]]]] == 0 && 
0 <= \[Omega] <= 1000, \[Omega], 5]
```

we got the warning:

> FindInstance was unable to prove that the solution set found is complete.

However, the zeros are given within plot range accordingly:

```
{{\[Omega] -> 255.326}, {\[Omega] -> 579.459}, {\[Omega] -> 894.145}}
```